# Windows 10 doesn't auto connect to network until I login after a restart

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, client-certificate

I have a Windows 10 laptop that is configured to connect to corporate BYOD (bring your own device) network. First time you connect to open guest network. Then from a web page, you download an executable that is supposedly install machine/user certificates tied to my user id. Once that is done, system detects byod network and connects to it fine.
Once I reboot and not login yet, it doesn't connect to network. Once I login it connects fine.

Is there anything I can do to make it auto connect to network without user having to login?

The thing is this laptop is in a lab and I like to connect to it using VNC. I can't do it because of this issue. Each time I have to be there and login first. Then I can connect from vnc viewer.

Comment: Does it begin the connection but you have to open the Wireless Networks box and click the "Connect" button one or more times?

Comment: @music2myear That is not the scenario I am running into. If I leave the system at login prompt for half an hour, it stays unconnected. You see the wifi icon for disconnected state. Once I login, it connects automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible explanation:**

I would guess this is due to the certificate only being valid for your user account, and therefore the computer cannot use it to authenticate to the network when you are not logged in.

You could ask IT if they authenticate network access by user account. If this is the case, that is the likely explanation as the authenticated user account must be logged in before the network will allow access.

**Source/background:**

At my organization we have a wireless network that requires policies applied to both specific computers AND users.

The computer policy includes the wireless connection profile.

The user policy contains the certificate necessary to complete the connection.

Computers will not connect to the wireless if they are not logged in, or if the user logged in to them does not have the necessary certificates installed or is not a member of the group the policies are attached to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the network administrator of the cooperate?

It seems that your network administrator has configured the 802.1 authentication in your network environment. This behavior is controlled by the network administrator but we could check the configuration from the network adapter properties.

[image]